# PowerBI: Assign Monthly Sales Target to individual Salesperson on a daily level

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a concern/inquiry about how to apply monthly level "sales target" on a daily, or weekly level.
Right now I have a separate "SalesTarget" table which does not really have a primary key because they are redundant, due to having different sales target for different month.

For example:

```
1. "salesperson": 10, "Start of Month": 2023-01-01, "Monthly Target": $30000, "Daily Target": $1500   
2. "salesperson": 20, "Start of Month": 2023-01-01, "Monthly Target": $50000, "Daily Target": $2000 
3. "salesperson": 10, "Start of Month": 2023-02-01, "Monthly Target": $40000, "Daily Target": $1600   
4. "salesperson": 20, "Start of Month": 2023-02-01, "Monthly Target": $60000, "Daily Target": $2500 
...
```

(Which means both keys "salesperson" and "Month", are not unique)

My relationship model looks like the following:

[image: Data Model]

In this model,
-salesperson connects to salesbudget on salesperson_id (1-many)
-calendar connects to salesbudget (1-many) on left = 'full_date', right = 'start of month'

Visual:

1. When i select on a monthly level or above, everything works fine:

[image: img2]

Problem:
2. When I select on a daily or weekly level, its not showing up the targets since there is only relationship on the "start of month" but not only other dates.

[image: img3]

Potential solution:

1. In the SalesBudget Table, duplicate the salesbudgets for all the days and use "first" when calculating DAX for sales budget (currently using SUM(SalesBudget)['Monthly Budget']
   Potential issue: SalesBudget table will not be very clean as for each saleseprson_id, there needs to be 365 rows for a year, and i have around 20 salesperson, 6 years data. Which I dont think is the best solution.

Question:
Is there a better way to achieve this goal? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this for always starting at the start of the month.

```
Budget = 
  CALCULATE(
    SUM(SalesBudget[Monthly_Budget]),
    DATESBETWEEN(
      calender[full_date],
      STARTOFMONTH(calender[full_date]),
      MAX(calender[full_date])
    )
  )
```

Comment: Hello there, If i add start of month in calendar table it will create many to many relationship since both tables contain duplicate start of month. Is there a solution for that? Thank you

Comment: Doh! Of course it does, my bad. I'll update the answer shorty.

Comment: Updated, keep it as you had it (ignore my previous answer).

Comment: You are amazing Sam! Saved my biggest headache!

Comment: Hello Sam, may I ask one more question? This DAX works great when the date level is <= month level as its MTD. when the range exceeds a month level, it will stay as the monthly target. Is there a way for it to adapt to a quarter or year slicer as well? For example, when selecting  a full year, the measure would be SUM(monthly target), I tried using YTD but has no luck with that. Thank you!

Comment: Updated the answer above, this version will work for both scenarios.